# testing - intentionally corrupt a .Z file using 'dd'

Tags: linux, unix, dd

I am trying to test my Python program, which takes in either .zip or .Z files and decompresses them using Python's `zipfile` module or Unix's `gzip`, respectively. It makes sure that the filetype is either .zip or .Z (in the latter case, using Unix's `file` command) before trying to do anything.  I wanted to test my error handling in the very rare case in which a verified archive file errors out while being decompressed. So basically, I want to feed it a corrupt .Z file.

Someone suggested that I could use Unix's `dd` command to just mess up a good .Z file and use that as my bad input. I couldn't find any examples for using `dd` for this use case and was hoping someone could provide a simple example. I know I shouldn't mess with the header, since that's where the metadata is that tells us it is a .Z file. So I know I need to mess up some of the middle and some of the end... Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just have used a hex editor like `hexedit`.

Since you ask though,

```bash
dd if=/dev/urandom of=yourfile.z bs=1024 seek=$((RANDOM%10)) count=1 conv=notrunc
```

will rewrite garbage to a random 1024b block out of the first ten in a file.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I ended up doing this to an original 140406 byte file (original.Z): `dd if=original.Z of=truncated.Z bs=1 count=140389`. Your above code might pick the first block as the random 1024 byte block, right? Which would mean it would say `not in gzip format` before it even tried to unzip it. I am unfamiliar with the $((%))syntax.

Comment: Takes care of the problem if you add a 1 to the arithmetic operation for the seek option: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=yourfile.z bs=1024 seek=$((RANDOM%10+1)) count=1 conv=notrunc`