# How do I corrupt openldap mdb database?

Tags: linux, openldap

I have an openldap container configured with cn=config and a database mounted in a persistent volume outside the container.

How can I corrupt the mdb?

For example, I would like to reproduce a corrupted database.
If I dump the database and I try to restore it, if I put invalid characters inside the ldif, or erase some parts or misspell the "objectClass" into "objectCalss" will it be considered corrupted?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: The question is if there is a way to corrupt the database, not if the integrity check works. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If there wasn't a way to corrupt the database there wouldnt be any need for an integrity check. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe with a short example I can explain it better. I will rephrase, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I would like to corrupt it while slapd is running. From another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130538/testing-intentionally-corrupt-a-z-file-using-dd)  I tried this: dd if=/dev/urandom of=db.mdb bs=1024 seek=$((RANDOM%10)) count=1 conv=notrunc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by another post: [testing - intentionally corrupt a .Z file using 'dd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130538/testing-intentionally-corrupt-a-z-file-using-dd)

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=db.mdb bs=1024 seek=$((RANDOM%10)) count=1 conv=notrunc
```